# Python to C and Garbage Collector

Tags: python, garbage-collection, ctype

I have the following problem in Python (problem with variable by ref or val in C)

My C Code:

```
#define NON_ALLOCATED 0
#define ALLOCATED 1
#define MAX_STACK 100

typedef struct myObject
{
   int iStatus;
   int iSize;
   double pdTab;
}

static myObject globaTab[MAX_STACK]

myObject *AllocateATab(int iSize)
{
   myObject *pxTab = NULL;
   int i;
   int iFound = 0;
   while(i < MAX_STACK && !iFound)
   {
      if (globaTab[i].iStatus = NON_ALLOCATED)
         iFound = 1;
         break;
   }
   if (i < MAX_STACK)
   {
      pxTab = globaTab + i;
      pxTab->iStatus = ALLOCATED;
      pxTab->pdTab = (double *)calloc(iSize, sizeof(double));
   }
   return pxTab;
}

int FreeATab(myObject *pxTab)
{
    if (pxTab)
    {
        pxTab->iStatus = NON_ALLOCATED;
        if (pxTab->pdTab)
           free(pxTab->pdTab);

    }
}

myObject *Scalar(double dValue)
{
    myObject *pxTab = AllocateATab(1000)
    for (int iSize = 0; iSize < 1000; iSize++)
       pxTab->pdTab[iSize] = dValue;

    return pxTab;

}
```

sample of my Python Code:

```
class MyClass(object):)
   def __del__(self):
      mylibC.FreeATab(self)

   def Scalar(valueinput):
      return mylibC.Scalar(valueinput)

   def transformValue(mylist):
        Len=len(mylist)
        res = [0]*Len
        for i in xrange(Len):
          if(type(mylist[i]) == float):
            res[i] = Scalar(mylist[i])
          else:
            res[i] = mylist[i]
        return res

    def myFunc(mylistlist):
        listValue = transformValue(mylist)
        return anotherCFunction(listValue)
```

When I use Scalar function status of myObject is equal to Allocated
However when I enter in anotherCFunction I see that status of object List is now to NON_ALLOCATED because python garbage collector has been called due to Scalar(mylist[i]) is a local called

Could you please help me to rewrite this python code in order that Python does not called garbage collector on List[i] ?
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what `MyFunc()` is supposed to do. Why have you shown us the definition of `TransformValue()` and not the definition of `TransformMacsValue()`? And what's `CFunction`? BTW, it's usual in Python to keep the names of simple variables and functions in lower case; capitalised names are used for classes.

Comment: I have edited my code (sorry for typo), I see that Python called destructor of my class where those function are encapsulated (garbage on Scalar(List[i]) because he considers it as local variable

Comment: There shouldn't be garbage collection problems with the code you've shown us. Can you show us the definition of `Scalar()`? What does `tab of double` mean? Thanks for fixing the case of your variable & function names, but now there's a new problem: using `list` as a variable name shadows the built-in `list()`, since plain variables and functions share the same name space.

Comment: sorry again I have tried to make a test case more sophisticated to explain my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *still* don't think that there are garbage collection problems with the code you've posted so far. But there are other significant problems with your Python code. (FWIW, the C code looks ok, I suppose you have been using C for a while but are still fairly new to Python). The biggest problem is that the definition of MyClass is faulty. You haven't shown us the code where you create an instance of MyClass and how you use it, so there may be additional problems.

When a class method is called it gets passed the class instance as the first argument, conventionally named `self`. This argument is not specified in the args given when you call the method but it *must* be specified in the method definition.

Eg,

```
class SimpleClass(object):
    def add(self, x, y):
        return x + y

simple = SimpleClass()
print simple.add_one(2, 3)
```

**output**

```
5
```

So the `add()` method is *defined* with three args, but when we call it we only supply two args explicitly, since the first arg, `self`, is implicit.

Most of your method definitions do *not* have `self` as their first arg, apart from your `__del__` method. Python doesn't care what you name your arguments, it will shove `self` into whatever is the first argument in the method's definition. So all your methods (apart from  `__del__`) are getting called with wrong args.

Also, when you call a method inside another method of that class you need to indicate that, normally by prefixing the method's name with `self.`. Eg

```
def transformValue(self, mylist):
    #The rest of the method definition
    #...

def myFunc(self, mylist):
    listValue = self.transformValue(mylist)
    return anotherCFunction(listValue)
```

Comment: sorry it is a mistake when I have tried to simplify my Python code those functions are not embedded in my class, thanks for your clarification

Comment: @parisjohn: Ah! That explains why Python didn't complain about the functions being called with the wrong number of arguments. :) I think you should fix the indentation of your code so that it's clear that those functions aren't supposed to be part of MyClass. And _please_ show us the code where you create an instance of MyClass and how you use it, so we can get to the real cause of your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help but my code is more complicated and for the moment I do not succeed to have a simple reproducer